# Last row of column using the column number

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This should be really easy, but I can't see it.

I've several columns, one for each team (over the range `shL.Range(S2:AA2)`). Below each team is a series of values which should be available in a Userform Listbox, depending on the team which has been selected.

I've got a code which reports the Column number of the team, and I'm trying to find the last row number based on that column. This is causing a Run-Time error 1004 (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed), which I expect is caused by `shL.Range(Cells(` but I'm not seeing how to fix it.

Is there a better way to find the last row of the column?

```
Dim y As Long, c As Long
Dim shE As Worksheet, shL As Worksheet, FoundTeam As Range
Set shE = Sheets("EnteredData")
Set shL = Sheets("Lookups")

Set FoundTeam = shL.Range("S2:AA2").Find(what:=shE.Range("D3"))
    c = FoundTeam.Column
    y = shL.Range(Cells(3, c) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

I appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with the concatenation, but try:

```
y = shL.Cells(shL.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Amazing. That seems to've done what I'm after. Thanks for that

Comment: You are welcome @Marc. Another small remark. You might also want to add an `If not FoundTeam is Nothing Then` like construction just to be safe before using this variable. If it has answered your question feel free to click the checkmark to the right of it to accept the answer as such.